# How to resolve the safe-cli error "Cannot find enough owners to sign." when trying to transfer an erc-721 NFT

Tags: safe-core

I am trying to transfer an erc-721 NFT. I have:

- signed in to the safe
- listed the owners
- Tried to transfer but got the error: `Cannot find enough owners to sign. 1 missing`

  blockchain > 0x7e1af7cB961...5E6d2Cc0d687D14F > show_cli_owners
  Account 0x6D5f3C3B373F37...8c313358FEb240 loaded
  Default sender: 0x6D5f3C3B373F37...8c313358FEb240
  blockchain > 0x7e1af7cB961...5E6d2Cc0d687D14F > send_erc721 0x12740c5a3...57588A77c1F66aEd 0x5A982d5852Af4...2AeA259211E9 1
  Cannot find enough owners to sign. 1 missing

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first load a private key corresponding to the owner of your Safe:

```
> load_cli_owners <account_private_key>
Loaded account 0xab...cd with balance=123 ether
Set account 0xab..cd as default sender of txs
```

You can also load owners from an environment variable. Before running the safe-cli:

```
export MY_PRIVATE_KEY=YOUR_EOA_PRIVATE_KEY
```

Then:

```
> load_cli_owners MY_PRIVATE_KEY
Loaded account 0xab...cd with balance=123 ether
Set account 0xab..cd as default sender of txs
```

To check your address has been correctly loaded:

```
> show_cli_owners
```

Hope it helps, Louis